# Why is LIKE more than 4x faster than MATCH...AGAINST on a FULLTEXT index in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I'm not getting this.

I've got a table with these indexes

```
PRIMARY     post_id
INDEX       topic_id
FULLTEXT    post_text
```

Table has (only) 346 000 rows. I am trying to perform 2 queries.

```
SELECT post_id 
FROM phpbb_posts 
WHERE topic_id = 144017 
AND post_id != 155352 
AND MATCH(post_text) AGAINST('http://rapidshare.com/files/5494794/photo.rar')
```

takes 4.05 seconds while

```
SELECT post_id 
FROM phpbb_posts 
WHERE topic_id=144017 
AND post_id != 155352 
AND post_text LIKE ('%http://rapidshare.com/files/5494794/photo.rar%')
```

takes 0.027 seconds.

EXPLAIN shows that the only difference is in possible_keys (`fulltext` has post_text included, `LIKE` does not)

That's really strange.

What's behind this? What's happening in the background? How can `LIKE` be so fast when not using index and FULLTEXT so slow when using its index?

## UPDATE1:

Actually it now takes about 0.5 seconds, maybe table was locked, but still, when I turn on profiling it's show that FULLTEXT INITIALIZATION took 0.2seconds. What's up?

I can query my table with `LIKE` 10x a second, with fulltext only 2x

## UPDATE2:

Surprise!

```
mysql> SELECT post_id FROM phpbb_posts WHERE post_id != 2 AND topic_id = 6 AND MATCH(post_text) AGAINST ('rapidshare.com');
Empty set (0.04 sec)
```

so I'm asking, how is this possible?

Additionally,

```
SELECT count(*) FROM phpbb_posts WHERE MATCH(post_text) AGAINST ('rapidshare.com')
```

is really slow. Can be fulltext any broken?

## UPDATE3:

What the hell?

```
SELECT forum_id, post_id, topic_id, post_text  FROM phpbb_posts  WHERE MATCH(post_text) AGAINST ('rapidshare.com') LIMIT 0, 30;
```

takes 0.27s while

```
SELECT count(*) FROM phpbb_posts  WHERE MATCH(post_text) AGAINST ('rapidshare.com') LIMIT 0, 30;
```

takes more than 30 seconds! What is going wrong here?

Comment: Are the response times between the two consistent over multiple runs?  I'm tempted to think disk caching may be coming into play where a first "slow" test loads all the data needed into ram so the second "fast" query is, well fast.

Comment: Test queries only with [SQL_NO_CACHE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/181905/318765).

Comment: This is pretty old question / answer. Any advancements from mysql / mariadb since those days?

Comment: **Caution:  The timing of this Q&A implies that it is talking only about MyISAM.  Its applicability to InnoDB is in question.**

Comment: @RomanSusi - Would you like to start a new question aimed at InnoDB?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem may stem from the presence of the FULLTEXT index itself.

Every time there is a query involving a FULLTEXT index, the MySQL Query Optimizer tends to whack the query into a full table scan. I have seen this over the years. [I also wrote an earlier post about this most trifling behavior in FULLTEXT indexes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/11730/877).

You may need to do two things:

1. refactor the query so that the FULLTEXT index does not throw the MySQL Query Optimizer into a state of confusion
2. Add an additional index that will properly support the refactored query

## REFACTOR THE QUERY

Here is your original query

```
SELECT post_id  
FROM phpbb_posts  
WHERE topic_id = 144017  
AND post_id != 155352  
AND MATCH(post_text) AGAINST('http://rapidshare.com/files/5494794/photo.rar')
```

You will need to refactor the query like this:

```
SELECT subqueryA.post_id
FROM
(
    SELECT post_id FROM phpbb_posts
    WHERE topic_id = 144017
    AND post_id != 155352
) subqueryA
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT post_id FROM phpbb_posts
    WHERE MATCH(post_text) AGAINST('http://rapidshare.com/files/5494794/photo.rar')
) subqueryB
USING (post_id);
```

## CREATE A NEW INDEX

You will need an index to support `subqueryA`. You already have an index on `topic_id`. You need to replace it as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE phpbb_posts ADD INDEX topic_post_ndx (topic_id,post_id);
ALTER TABLE phpbb_posts DROP INDEX topic_id;
```

Give it a Try !!!

### **UPDATE 2012-03-19 13:08 EDT**

Try this one first

```
SELECT post_id FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM phpbb_posts
    WHERE topic_id = 144017
    AND post_id != 155352
) A;
```

If this runs fast and return a small number of rows, then try this nested subquery:

```
SELECT post_id FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM phpbb_posts
    WHERE topic_id = 144017
    AND post_id != 155352
) A
WHERE MATCH(post_text) AGAINST('http://rapidshare.com/files/5494794/photo.rar');
```

### **UPDATE 2012-03-19 13:11 EDT**

Compare the running time of this:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM phpbb_posts  WHERE MATCH(post_text) AGAINST ('rapidshare.com') LIMIT 0, 30;
```

with this

```
SELECT count(*) FROM phpbb_posts WHERE 1 = 1;
```

If there running time is the same, then the MATCH clause is being executed on every row. As I mentioend earlier, using FULLTEXT indexes tends to nullify any benefits attempted  and contributed by the MySQL Query Optimizer.

Comment: So you want to say that my query actually scan the whole table because topic_id and `post_id` confuses it? Why does the LIKE query work even without having index on these columns (topic_id, post_id)? Why doesn't MYSQL just intelligently select `topic_id = 144017 AND post_id != 155352` and then just browser through these results? And what if 100k rows includes my fulltext search string in `post_text`? Wouldn't it select them all?

Comment: Actually I'm confused even more. LIKE '%text%' doesn't use indexes either, it means it does scan the whole table, so why is it so fast?

Comment: Please look at my **UPDATE**, I think you'll solve it really fast. I'm going to give you my rep if you solve it.

Comment: Replying to your second update. Second query ran in less than 0.01ms, the first one didn't finish. Why did you say "If there running time is the same, then the MATCH clause is being executed on every row." ? Isn't it exactly the opposite of what it should be? If you look [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?107,216167,216167), you'll see I'm not the only with this problem

Comment: Replying to your first update. First query ran in 0.01ms, 0 rows, second one returned "Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list". However, your query with 2 subqueries works perfectly!

Comment: But again, I'm not getting why I did get results faster with `LIKE` ? Does it use index?

Comment: Both of your queries end up ditching indexes and doing full table scans. Since both do full table scans, it would seem that `MATCH ... AGAINST` is a more expensive (CPU intensive) operation than that of `LIKE`.