# Fulltext search using multiple indexes

Tags: mysql, index, full-text-search

I have a table with several columns, say `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` that should be searchable. The problem arises when I need to search `a, b, c` separately from `d` (and vise-versa). AFAIK, there's no way to achieve this using one composite fulltext index on all columns, so I create two separate indexes like this:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx1 ON content (a, b, c);
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx2 ON content (d);
```

Now I can search the first and second one successfully. For both of them, I would  use the following command:

```
SELECT * FROM content 
WHERE MATCH(a, b, c) AGAINST ('keyword')
AND MATCH(d) AGAINST ('keyword');
```

`explain` tells me this:

```
+----+-------------+---------+----------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type     | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------+----------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | content | fulltext | idx1,idx2     | idx1 | 0       |      |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------+----------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

Great! So it's using two indexes, but returns only rows where `keyword` is present in both inclusive and I need either one, so I change `AND` to `OR` and now explain says:

```
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | content | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |  128 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

What? Suddenly, it's doing a full table scan. Why is this happening? What would be the best way to avoid this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is how MySQL Query Optimizer treats FULLTEXT indexes. When a `MATCH` clause is the only clause in the `WHERE`, the index will be used. When used in conjunction with `AND`, the index may easily get overlooked.

I wrote about this behavior before in [Mysql fulltext search my.cnf optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11716/mysql-fulltext-search-my-cnf-optimization/11730#11730)

SUGGESTION : Rewrite the query as the union of two FULLTEXT searches

```
SELECT * FROM content 
WHERE MATCH(a, b, c) AGAINST ('keyword')
UNION
SELECT * FROM content 
WHERE MATCH(d) AGAINST ('keyword');
```

**GIVE IT A TRY !!!**

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, this gives me the desired result, however when run with `explain`, it now shows 3 actions instead of 1. Does this mean it actually doing more operations, or it comes down to one lookup internally?

Comment: Yes it does. It should be 3 operations, 1 resultset from `MATCH(a, b, c)`, 1 resultset from `MATCH(d)`, and a merger of the two resultsets.

Answer (score 0):

Unclear what you want to do.

If you want to see rows with `keyword` in both `d` and somewhere in `a,b,c`, then your `AND` is a good way to go.

But if you want `keyword` to be in any of `a,b,c,d`, then add a *third* index

```
FULLTEXT(a,b,c,d)
```

and change to

```
MATCH(a,b,c,d) AGAINST('keyword')
```

For further discussion please specify whether you are using InnoDB or MyISAM; they work differently.

Comment: This way I'll have 3 indexes, one of which is completely redundant. Plus, on every `INSERT`, MySQL would have to rebuild all three of them. Seems like too much extra operations for a simple search feature. Using MyISAM.

Comment: MySQL does not "rebuild" indexes on each `INSERT`; it just augments the indexes.  This is cheap enough not to be a big issue.  I `think` MyISAM does not need the third `FULLTEXT`, but InnoDB does, hence my question.

Comment: That's nice to know, thanks. It doesn't absolutely _need_ the third FULLTEXT, but in that case it's doing full table scan, which I'm trying to avoid. My original question was why does MySQL treat `AND` so differently from `OR` in a single query, when internally it should be implemented the same way. There doesn't seem to be much information online about this behavior, except for the question [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?107,402019,402243), which basically says "`OR` is not optimized, while `AND` is"

Comment: Yes.  `AND` can often be optimized, often with a different index.  `OR` is rarely optimizable.  Often `UNION` is a trick to optimize it, as Rolando points out.